# goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory

Tags: java, maven

I have a pom.xml in my project folder and when i run maven command(mvn clean) in my CMD i am getting below error and can some one help on it.

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
'T' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
The directory name is invalid.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.114 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-06-11T19:00:01+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/184M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (C:\). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProjectException
```

Comment: Please, post your pom.

Comment: You are obviously invoking Maven from `C:\` although that is probably not your intention. Can you publish the whole input and output?

Comment: @JFabianMeier you want me to post my pom.xml?

Comment: I want you to post the directory from which you are invoking this and the complete command. There are two strange things here: There seems to be a `T` in the command and it seems to be invoked from `C:`. So there is probably some mistake in how you start the command.

Comment: C:\AT&T\EPO_LATEST\externalpartnerorderms_rk>mvn clean

Comment: @JFabianMeier i used above command

Comment: I think the `&` in the path is the problem. This would explain why the process tries to run a command with name `T`.

Comment: @JFabianMeier let me remove & and retry it

Comment: Thanks now it's working

Answer (score 0):

you should run mvn clean command in the path of pom.xml

for example if you have pom.xml in C:\javapro\first_example then you should run the command in this path.

Comment: i run in same location

Comment: what is the command you are trying to run ?